# How to call method from another class in java?

Tags: java, swing

i am trying to call the method from another class in java, when calling the method i want to pass the date variable to method, how can i do this?
is what i am doing is right?

Code:

Function:

```
    public static int search(java.util.Date date)
    {

    }
```

calling function like this:

```
Date dt = new Date();
search(dt);
```

Comment: Read a tutorial on Java.

Comment: You need an instance of the other class; ie `instanceOfOtherClass.search(dt)`...

Comment: what seems to be the problem ?

Comment: Try improving your question, is to vague

Answer (score 1):

1. Check the class, where your 'search' method is located. For example, if it is in a class called 'Main', then you should use Main.search(dt).
2. Your 'search' returns an 'int' in signature. Make sure, that you actually return something from the method.

And follow @Uwe Plonus suggestion - read a tutorial.